# npm 'connect' version

Tags: node.js, connect, npm

I'm unable to install "connect" package with npm.
npm says that the latest valid version is 1.0.1 but on npm server it's 2.0.1

npm version is 1.1.4 and node is 0.7.6pre

```
npm install connect@'>=2.0.1'
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect

npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: connect@'>=2.0.1'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR!     ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.0.4","0.0.5","0.0.6","0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","0.2.5","0.2.6","0.2.7","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2","0.5.3","0.5.4","0.5.5","0.5.6","0.5.7","0.5.8","0.5.9","0.5.10","1.0.0","1.0.1"]
```

you think i should use node v0.6.12 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to downgrade to something below 0.7.0 to use the most recent version of connect. Starting with connect 1.0.2, they set a maximum node version for the package. See http://search.npmjs.org/#/connect.

Answer (score 2):

I checked installing connect module in node version 0.6.12 for Windows, with command:

```
npm install connect@2.0.3
```

and it got installed successfully!